# LogicalBytesPerSector vs PhysicalBytesPerSector

Tags: windows, winapi, storage, hard-drive, sector

When I do the command `fsutil fsinfo sectorInfo c:`, I receive this output:

```
LogicalBytesPerSector :                                 512
PhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity :                    4096
PhysicalBytesPerSectorForPerformance :                  4096
FileSystemEffectivePhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity : 4096 Device
Alignment :                                      Aligned (0x000)
Partition alignment on device :                         Aligned
(0x000) No Seek Penalty Trim Supported Not DAX capable Not
Thinly-Provisioned
```

I'm worried about the difference between `LogicalBytesPerSector` and `PhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity`.

As `LogicalBytesPerSector` is less than `PhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity`, will every block of 512 bytes I write actually be written atomically? On the other hand, will every block of 4096 bytes I write actually be written atomically?

Also, will the read/write of 512 bytes be slow, as if I understand well, the system will need to read 4096 physical bytes just to write my 512 bytes?

Comment: this is [`FILE_FS_SECTOR_SIZE_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/3e75d97f-1d0b-4e47-b435-73c513837a57)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does every block of 512 bytes I will wrote will be wrote atomically ? on the other way does every block of 4096 Bytes I will wrote will be wrote atomically?

4096 will write atomically.

512 will write atomically with possibly writing other data to complete to 4096.

> Also does the read/wrote of 512 bytes will be not too much slow as, if I understand well, the system will need to read 4096 Physical bytes just to wrote my 512 bytes?

Yes, at least write by `PhysicalBytesPerSectorForPerformance`. By more may be still faster due to more efficient commands utilization.